# How to use regex in a Capybara finder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, capybara

The following works great:

```
find "img[src='https://www.example.com/image']"
```

But I want to also find

```
find "img[src='https://www.example.com/image?foo=bar']"
```

How to use a regex within the attribute in the finder?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can check that an attribute starts with a certain value using `^=`:

```
find("img[src^='https://www.example.com/image']")
```

The article, [The Skinny on CSS Attribute Selectors](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/), describes the various checks (equals, starts with, ends with, etc.):

```
#Equals
find("img[src='https://www.example.com/image']")

#Contains somewhere
find("img[src*='https://www.example.com/image']")

#Begins with
find("img[src^='https://www.example.com/image']")

#Ends with
find("img[src$='https://www.example.com/image']")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `class` option, as in `find("div", class: /some-class/)`.